# Window.location not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I'm new to JS, and I wanna redirect the user to another page...

My code:

```
// Below function Executes on click of login button.
function validate() {
  redirectTo =
    window.location.protocol + window.location.host + "/dashboard.html";
  var username = document.getElementById("userName").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("passWord").value;
  if (username == "admin" && password == "password") {
    window.location = redirectTo; // Redirecting to other page.
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("NANI!!!");
  }
}
```

I know this is not a secure way to auth, but relax it's just a portfolio project

Comment: Do you get any errors when trying `window.location`? What results you expect?

Comment: For one thing, window.location.protocol doesn't give you the "//" you need after the protocol in a URL. Log the value of `redirectTo` and see what you get

Comment: it says

```
unreachable code after return statement
```

Comment: @H4CKTRIK Don't understand what's ```. Update your whole function in the answer below, please have a look, and check if there is any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should append the '//' after `window.location.protocol` which mentioned by @Vasan.

Using ES6 template strings would make it clear.

```
  function validate() {
    const redirectTo = `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.host}/dashboard.html`;
    const username = document.getElementById('userName').value;
    const password = document.getElementById('passWord').value;
    if (username === 'admin' && password === 'password') {
      window.location = redirectTo; // Redirecting to other page.
      return false;
    } else {
      alert('NANI!!!');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `window.location.href = redirectTo`.

Comment: Nope, window.location works just as fine. Try it in your browser console